# Extension of ample vector bundles is ample

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, ample-bundles

As I read Huybrechts-Lehn's book on Moduli of Sheaves, it is making a claim that extensions of several (at least 2) ample vector bundles (on curves) is again ample. Somehow, I am unable to see this right away from Hartshorne's definition of ample vector bundle. Can someone either show me a proof or direct me to reference for this?

P.S. Is it necessary to assume that the base is a curve for above statement to hold?

Comment: This is true on any projective variety, see Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II*, Proposition 6.1.13 (ii).

Comment: @abx This is no true in positive characteristic. For the general theory, see the first part of Martin-Dechamps, Propriétés de descente des variétés à fibré cotangent ample." Annales de l'institut Fourier 34.3 (1984).

Comment: @DamianRössler So you claim Lazarsfeld Remark 6.1.17 is wrong? I think you may be mistaken, because your reference is talking about extending an ample vector bundle by the trivial one.

Comment: @CountDracula: Lazarsfeld's standing hypothesis is that all schemes are over $\mathbb{C}$.  Since many of his earlier preparatory arguments use Hodge theory, etc., this is a fairly important hypothesis in the book.  Of course, Hartshorne's Corollary 3.4 has no such hypothesis.  This is the correct reference.

Comment: @JasonStarr This is why I referenced his Remark 6.1.17 where Lazarsfeld explicitly discusses char p.

Comment: @CountDracula: You are correct; I commented too quickly.  I looked at Proposition 6.1.13 without looking at Remark 6.1.17.  Anyway, I think it is better to give a reference to a specific result in Hartshorne, namely, Corollary 3.4. Lazarsfeld does not specifically cite Corollary 3.4 for this step of the proof.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes you are right, that is better.

Comment: @JasonStarr For Hartshorne's Corollary 3.4, I am unable to locate such statement in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book. Do you either mean Residues and Duality or some other reference by Hartshorne. Can you be more specific on this please?

Comment: @chhan92: "Ample Vector Bundles" by Robin Hartshorne,   Pub. Math. de l'IHÉS (1966) Vol. 29, pp 63-94. https://eudml.org/doc/103864

Comment: @Count Dracula. Sorry I commented too quickly. The fact that the extension of an ample bundle by another ample bundle is ample is not very difficult to prove (see Jason's reference) but it is a subtle fact that in char. 0, a non-trivial extension of an ample bundle by a trivial bundle is ample. This is also proven in Lazarsfeld's book (and it false in char. p>0).